# Setting CLS compliance for a .NET assembly

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, cls-compliant

Setting CLS compliance for an entire .NET assembly is possible. But how is it actually done? E.g. with Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Visual Studio adds a directive for the compiler, and the compiler checks the code for some more strict rules than in the native programming language.

You can add the CLS compliant attribute to all your project by adding the assembly level attribute

```
[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]
```

anywhere in your project, generally in the `assemblyinfo.cs` file.

If the line `using System;` is not at the top of the file, add it. Or, use the long form:

```
[assembly: System.CLSCompliant(true)]
```

Answer (score 21):

You need to add this line to one of your source files:

```
[assembly: System.CLSCompliant(true)]
```

More info on CLS compliant code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f(loband).aspx).

Normally you put this in assemblyinfo.cs